# Sybase BCP out with null values

Tags: sybase, bcp

Is there a way to get BCP out to return NULL values rather then just blanks

Current Output:

```
'apse0420', '', '2', '2'
```

What I want:

```
'apse0420', 'NULL', '2', '2'
```

BCP out code:

```
bcp <db>..<table> out test.txt -S <server> -U <username> -P <password> -c -t ", " -r "\n"
```

Comment: create a view from table and convert `NULL` columns into string 'NULL'. BCP out the view

Comment: @Meet You should probably submit that as an answer - I was going to suggest the same thing, so I would have up-voted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a view from table and convert `NULL` columns into string 'NULL'. BCP out the view